# MS SQL и тип связи "Категория"

Tags: sql, база-данных, sql-server

Имеется 3 сущности:

1. User - описывает общие атрибуты
2. Категория - физическое лицо
3. Категория - юридическое лицо

Как правильно организовать ограничение целостности данных, что бы User мог находится только в одной категории?

На ум приходит следующее:

1. Повесить триггеры на категории, что бы при добавлении Юзера в категорию, проверялась противоположная категория на предмет наличия Юзера в 1 из категорий
2. Создать процедуру, в которой в рамках единой транзакции будет создаваться записи в : User+Юридическое лицо или User+Физическое лицо

Что наиболее верно и нет ли еще способов?

Comment: Имхо, не категории должны ссылаться на юзера, а наоборот, юзер — на категории. Соответственно, у Users будет 2 внешних ключа на таблицы категорий, и соответствующий constraint, что-нибудь вроде этого: `CHECK (CASE WHEN fk1 IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END + CASE WHEN fk2 IS NULL TNEN 0 ELSE 1  END = 1)` (это если юзер обязательно должен относиться к одной из двух категорий). А вообще, наиболее правильный способ — не давать модифицировать записи в таблицах вручную, и необходимую логику обеспечивать хранимыми процедурами.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно обойтись без триггеров, т.е. сделать декларативное ограничение целостности - CHECK + UDF. Похожая проблема рассмотрена [здесь](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_subqueries_in_check_constraints.html).

Comment: Похоже, то что нужно. Спасибо!

Comment: Что будет работать быстрее: CHECK, который будет вызывать функцию, которая в свою очередь будет заглядывать в противоположную категориюили триггер, который будет делать аналогичные действия?

Comment: Проведите эксперименты. Или вы предпочитаете верить на слово? :-)

Answer (score 1):

По моему опыту работы в банковской сфере наиболее верное решение - это разделение юридических и физических лиц по разным таблицам (в 3 банках, в которых я работал - TOP 10 в России, сделано именно так). Данное решение объясняется очень просто - атрибуты юридических и физических лиц очень сильно отличаются.